# Computing bincount (or spectrum) of matrix over large range in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to implement a notion of the diversity of the elements of a matrix in Tensorflow efficiently such that it can be performed on every iteration of a neural network training. More precisely,

- Input: A large matrix,`A` of integers `H x L` ranging from `[0,2^K)` where `K` is large.
- Output: A vector of integers, or spectrum of the matrix, `s` of size `H*L + 1` where `s[i]` represents the number of integers in `[0, 2^K)` that is repeated `i` times.
- Computational considerations: `H x L = 32*400` and `K = 16`. This procedure would need to be run on every iteration of a neural network.

**Example:**

```
A = [[0,0,0,1,1,2,2],
     [3,4,4,4,4,5,6]]
K = 3
s = [1,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

**Naive Approach**

```
I = tf.one_hot(A) #Shape: H x L x 2^K
y = tf.reduce_sum(tf.reduce_sum(I,0),1) # Shape: 2^K
s = tf.bincount(y, minLength = H*L + 1) # Shape: H*L + 1
```

Unfortunately, the main issue with this approach is that expanding to the one_hot form for moderately sized `K` becomes computationally infeasible and can run into out of memory issues as well. Is there are more efficient way to do this in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call bincount once on the matrix you'll get a vector where in position i you have the count of element i. Then, if you call bincount on that you'll have a vector where in position c you have the number of elements which had count c, which is what I think you want.